# Query to retrieve the Datetime for ALL the messages received by the given Receive Location

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Purpose: Query to retrieve the Datetime for ALL the messages received by the given Receive Location.

Usgage: Execute this SQL query in BizTalkDTADb database. Provide the ReceiveLocation name in the commented place.

```
SELECT  
     RP.nvcName    [ReceivePortName] 
    ,RL.Name    [ReceiveLocationName]    
    ,MF.[Event/Adapter] [Adapter]
    ,RL.InboundTransportURL    [InboundTransportURL]
    ,MF.[Event/Timestamp]    [MessageReceivedDateTime]        
 FROM 
BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.adm_ReceiveLocation RL
JOIN BizTalkMgmtDb.dbo.bts_receiveport RP ON RP.nID = RL.ReceivePortId
JOIN BizTalkDTADb.dbo.dtav_MessageFacts MF ON MF.[Event/Port] = RP.nvcName
AND MF.[Event/URL] = RL.InboundTransportURL

--Give the ReceiveLocation Name 
(I replace RL location name when executing this query)                                           
WHERE    RL.Name='<<ReceiveLocation Name>>' AND
MF.[Event/Direction] = 'Receive'
ORDER BY MessageReceivedDateTime DESC
```

When I ran this query using SQLManagementstudio I'm not getting anything and query create only table header without data though I have seen from BizTalk Admin console message arrived and process through orchestration. 
please check where there I have problem with SQL query ?

Comment: Did you retrieve the SQL query from https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Querying-for-messages-0dbe3259? The query works for me (BizTalk 2013 R2), just make sure your Receive Location Name is the right one.

Comment: Yep that's true but in my case it's not retrieving though I place correct receive location - thank for checking @PieterVandenheede

Comment: Could it be that you do not have any tracking enabled or nothing passed through that receive location?